# Update and save vacation at the end of the month

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I have an Excel sheet where I track the vacation taken. At the end of each month I want to keep trace of how many days each employee had used.
Vacations taken are in C4 - C20 and end of month date are in D4 - O20, each column being a month end data. How do I copy the data from C4 - C20 to each column at the end of each month?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your data?

Comment: Not really clear question, what, could you provide example!

Comment: The number of days booked for vacation are captured in column C. At the end of the month I want to copy that number into Column D. So cell C4 data copied to D4 on the last day of the month but not erased after that. I think I just answered my own question... if I use an IF function and compare TODAY() with last day of the month and if FALSE just set to the same cell (circular reference) it should work. I will try that.

Comment: Yes this did work. Although I was able to solve my own question this site was a big help. You asked for more information which made me think and got my brain going, LOL. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Number of vacation days in captured in cell C4.
At the end of the month I want this data captured in D4 and not updated after that date.
End of the month date in set in D11

Solution: =IF(TODAY()=D11,C4,D4)

After the date is passed the data in D4 does not update.

Comment: In this forum, we ask that an `Answer` be used for **Answers**.  This post appears to be a clarification of your question.  If it is meant to be an Answer, my apologies, and you'll be able to accept it in a few days.  If it is a clarification, please delete this answer and **edit** your original question to provide the clarification.